# Return a nested data structure from a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

If I have a graph with this kind of structure:

```
@prefix  :       <http://example/> .
@prefix  rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix  foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

:alice rdf:type        foaf:Person .
:alice foaf:givenName  "Alice" .
:alice foaf:familyName "Liddell" .

:bob   rdf:type        foaf:Person .
:bob   foaf:givenName  "Bob" .
:bob   foaf:familyName "Doe" .

:choi  rdf:type        foaf:Person .
:choi  foaf:givenName  "Hwa" .
:choi  foaf:familyName "Choi" .

:alice :knows          :bob, :choi .
```

How do I obtain the names of people who Alice knows, in some structured format? Ideal format would be something like:

```
[
  {
    "given": "Alice",
    "family": "Liddell",
    "knows": [
      { "given": "Bob", "family": "Doe" },
      { "given": "Hwa", "family": "Choi" }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I only wanted an array of a single attribute, I could do something like:

```
SELECT ?name, (group_concat(distinct ?name;separator="|||") as ?friend_names)
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:givenName ?name,
  ?person :knows ?friend .
  ?friend foaf:givenName ?friend_name
}
GROUP BY ?name
```

And then, *assuming `|||` doesn't occur in any names*, unpack the results.

Is there a way to get the above response structure with more than one attribute (e.g. `given` and `family`), ideally without hardcoded separator tricks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `CONSTRUCT` query with [JSON-LD Framing](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-framing/).

**Example query** (on [DBpedia endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql))

```
CONSTRUCT
{
  ?person  rdf:type       foaf:Person ;
           dbo:birthName  ?name1s ;
           dbo:birthDate  ?date1s ;
           dbo:spouse     ?spouse .
  ?spouse  rdf:type       foaf:Person ; 
           dbo:birthName  ?name2s ;
           dbo:birthDate  ?date2s .
}
WHERE
{
  ?person  dbo:birthName  ?name1 ;
           dbo:birthDate  ?date1 ;
           dbo:spouse     ?spouse .
  ?spouse  dbo:birthName  ?name2 ;
           dbo:birthDate  ?date2 .
  BIND (str(?name1) AS ?name1s)
  BIND (str(?date1) AS ?date1s)
  BIND (str(?name2) AS ?name2s)
  BIND (str(?date2) AS ?date2s)
  VALUES (?person) { ( dbr:Brad_Pitt ) }
}
```

**Output** (in [JSON-LD format](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=CONSTRUCT%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson++rdf%3Atype+++++++foaf%3APerson+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3AbirthName++%3Fname1s+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3AbirthDate++%3Fdate1s+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3Aspouse+++++%3Fspouse+.%0D%0A++%3Fspouse++rdf%3Atype+++++++foaf%3APerson+%3B+%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3AbirthName++%3Fname2s+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3AbirthDate++%3Fdate2s+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson++dbo%3AbirthName++%3Fname1+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3AbirthDate++%3Fdate1+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3Aspouse+++++%3Fspouse+.%0D%0A++%3Fspouse++dbo%3AbirthName++%3Fname2+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbo%3AbirthDate++%3Fdate2+.%0D%0A++BIND+%28str%28%3Fname1%29+AS+%3Fname1s%29%0D%0A++BIND+%28str%28%3Fdate1%29+AS+%3Fdate1s%29%0D%0A++BIND+%28str%28%3Fname2%29+AS+%3Fname2s%29%0D%0A++BIND+%28str%28%3Fdate2%29+AS+%3Fdate2s%29%0D%0A++VALUES+%28%3Fperson%29+%7B+%28+dbr%3ABrad_Pitt+%29+%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=application%2Fx-json%2Bld%2Bctx&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000) with context)

```js
{ "@context": {
    "spouse": { "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/spouse"},
    "birthDate": { "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate" },
    "birthName": { "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthName" } },
  "@graph": [
    { "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angelina_Jolie",
      "birthName": "Angelina Jolie Voight",
      "birthDate": "1975-06-04" },
    { "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Brad_Pitt",
      "@type": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person",
      "birthName": "William Bradley Pitt",
      "spouse": [ "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angelina_Jolie",
                  "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jennifer_Aniston" ],
      "birthDate": "1963-12-18" },
    { "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jennifer_Aniston",
      "birthName": "Jennifer Joanna Aniston",
      "birthDate": "1969-02-11" }
] }
```

**JSON-LD Frame** (very simple)

```js
{
  "@context": {"dbo": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/",
               "dbr": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/",
               "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"},
  "dbo:spouse": {
   }
}
```

**Framed JSON-LD** ([playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22spouse%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fspouse%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22birthDate%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthDate%22%7D%2C%22birthName%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthName%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAngelina_Jolie%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2FPerson%22%2C%22birthName%22%3A%22Angelina%20Jolie%20Voight%22%2C%22birthDate%22%3A%221975-06-04%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FBrad_Pitt%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2FPerson%22%2C%22birthName%22%3A%22William%20Bradley%20Pitt%22%2C%22spouse%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAngelina_Jolie%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FJennifer_Aniston%22%5D%2C%22birthDate%22%3A%221963-12-18%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FJennifer_Aniston%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2FPerson%22%2C%22birthName%22%3A%22Jennifer%20Joanna%20Aniston%22%2C%22birthDate%22%3A%221969-02-11%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22dbo%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%22%2C%22dbr%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%22%2C%22foaf%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%22%7D%2C%22dbo%3Aspouse%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&context=%7B%7D))

```js
{
  "@context": {
    "dbo": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/",
    "dbr": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/",
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "dbr:Brad_Pitt",
      "@type": "foaf:Person",
      "dbo:birthDate": "1963-12-18",
      "dbo:birthName": "William Bradley Pitt",
      "dbo:spouse": [
        {
          "@id": "dbr:Angelina_Jolie",
          "@type": "foaf:Person",
          "dbo:birthDate": "1975-06-04",
          "dbo:birthName": "Angelina Jolie Voight"
        },
        {
          "@id": "dbr:Jennifer_Aniston",
          "@type": "foaf:Person",
          "dbo:birthDate": "1969-02-11",
          "dbo:birthName": "Jennifer Joanna Aniston"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Some discussion**

JSON-LD Framing is an unofficial, yet well implemented specification that describes a deterministic layout for serializing an RDF graph into a particular JSON-LD document layout.

Obviously, with [blank nodes property lists](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#grammar-production-blankNodePropertyList), one can achieve something structurally similar to the output you want:

```
Brad_Pitt
        dbo:birthName   "William Bradley Pitt" ;
        dbo:birthDate   "1963-12-18" .
        dbo:spouse  [   dbo:birthName   "Angelina Jolie Voight" ;
                        dbo:birthDate   "1975-06-04" ] ,
                    [   dbo:birthName   "Jennifer Joanna Aniston" ;
                        dbo:birthDate   "1969-02-11" ] .
```

However, this is Turtle, not JSON, and nobody can garantee that these blank nodes property lists will be used in serialization.

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating the query result itself (essentially an abstract table structure) with the syntax in which that result is written (in your case, a customized nested JSON structure).

Don't try to do tricks with group concatenation in this case. Just do this query:

```
SELECT ?given ?family ?friend_given ?friend_family
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:givenName ?given ;
          foaf:familyName ?family .
  ?person :knows ?friend .
  ?friend foaf:givenName ?friend_given ;
          foaf:familyName ?friend_family .
}
GROUP BY ?family ?given
```

Which results in a result like this:

```
given  family  friend_given friend_family
-------------------------------------------- 
Alice  Lidell  Bob          Doe
Alice  Lidell  Hwa          Choi
```

And then let a custom streaming result writer write the result to the nested syntax format you require. Given that the query groups by name, the writer can safely assume that subsequent rows with the same given and family names "belong together".

Alternatively, use a CONSTRUCT query instead of a SELECT, and post-process the retrieved RDF graph (which accurately represents the tree structure you're after).

Comment: In my real query, where quite a few attributes of the original person are fetched as well, this will result in a much bigger response size, which is undesirable.

Comment: @Koterpillar in that case my second suggestion (using CONSTRUCT) is probably a good solution. Apart from that however, most SPARQL databases are quite good at streaming data from query results as well as efficiently compressing data when sending over the wire - so the response size _really_ shouldn't be a major issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers do not mention the danger of Cartesian explosion. If you have mulivalued fields of the root person, these will be multiplied by the multiple related persons, creating unnecessary rows.
A construct may collapse those extra rows, but still: the worry should not make them in the first place. So use Union instead of straight patterns.