# Display SPARQL query results as nested JSON object

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This SPARQL query shows the list of US presidents and their spouses. How do I list the spouse names as a nested JSON object and group the query by president ID and president name?
Example of a president with multiple spouses: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22686

Here's the [URL for the query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fp%20%3FpLabel%20%3Fw%20%3FwLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20wd%3AQ30%20p%3AP6%2Fps%3AP6%20%3Fp%20.%0A%20%20%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Fw%20.%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D):

```
SELECT ?p ?pLabel ?w ?wLabel WHERE {
   wd:Q30 p:P6/ps:P6 ?p .
   ?p wdt:P26 ?w .
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }
 }
```

Spouse: P26

Start time: P580

End time: P582

Wanted to get something like thhis:

```
{
    "pLabel":"John Smith",
    "spouses": {
        "wLabel":"Jane Doe",
        "start_time":"2010-02-10",
        "end_time":"2017-05-11"
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You have two questions: the first one is about working with Wikidata qualifiers, the second one is about JSON serialization structure. Both questions are duplicates. The first one is a duplicate of (e. g.) https://stackoverflow.com/q/46383784/7879193 . The second one is a duplicate of (e.g.) https://stackoverflow.com/q/44622486/7879193 .